# How to send a linked server name as a parameter of stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to create a simple stored procedure which queries with Linked server.

```
create procedure test
@LinkedServeName nvarchar(20)
as
begin
  select * from @LinkedServerName.WorkersDB.tbl_workers
end
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to use dynamic TSQL.

Please read: [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html)

Comment: Thanks @Mitch Wheat but I'm looking for the other suggestion.

Comment: here is a solution for database name (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943823/sql-server-how-to-get-a-database-name-as-a-parameter-in-a-stored-procedure)

Comment: Plus, if you already know the answers why are you asking a question?

Comment: because this solution is for database name not for linked server name

Comment: plus, I can't use the use clause for a linked server name so I'm looking for the other solution